# How to use Transvoxel tables

Tags: voxels, marching-cubes

Could someone explain how to use the lookup tables provided on http://transvoxel.org/ with the regular Marching Cubes algorithm?

I'm not even talking about the whole LOD System etc. I actually understand how that is supposed to work and why Transvoxel uses different tables, I just can't seem to figure out what modifications to make to the regular Marching Cubes algorithm to use them.

Comment: [There's a write-up and example of decoding a cell into its corresponding lookup table entry in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/142503/39518) — does that cover what you need? If not, can you explain where you get stuck in applying it to your implementation?